# Listview RollOver RollOut

Tags: java, android

What events do I need to listen to imitate rollover and rollout on a listview item. I want to change the colour of some text on rollover and change it back on rollover.

Comment: What does rollover and rollout mean?

Comment: In particular, what does rollover and rollout mean on a device has no mouse?

Comment: I think this is just focus. Rollover/Rollout with a trackball makes sense ... or at least some ;)  Checkout ColorState list. Set your text color to a colorstate list with a special color set for state_focus=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

Went with the setOnTouchListener. Using MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN etc... I could simulate the gesture of RollOver RollOut in the context of touch.